# What is the best YOU TUBE API to search videos by keyword in IOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I want to search you tube videos by keyword using YOU TUBE API.

Is there any YOU TUBE API's with best results..while searching for videos.

I used YOU TUBE API V2 using below link

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/fun?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1

But it is not accurate..

Any Suggestions will be appreciated..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current search feed is not searching for videos whose metadata contains the word 'fun,' but is searching instead for videos where the category metadata contains the word 'fun' " (that's why the results are all in the Entertainment, Games, etc. categories). So instead, in V2, you'd want to send a query string:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=fun&v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1
```

However, the 'best results' that you ask for will be achieved through the v3 search endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=fun&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: is there any way to use above mentioned query strings without mentioning `API_KEY`? In other words, I'm looking for a public (without needs to register and get api keys) Youtube API's that finds a video by mentioning `keyword`. Thanks in advance

Comment: The older v2 queries don't need a key; the v3 queries do (unless it's a query that requires an oAuth scope authentication, like an upload). You'll want to register and use the key, though, as the benefits outweigh the minimal effort it takes ... you are granted 5,000,000 quota units per day for a single API key.